# Is there any good way to represent the order change before and after sorting on a value in a data frame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, plotly

I have a Pandas data-frame and I will be sorting it on a particular column. If I want to plot the data to represent how the data is changing before and after sorting, is there any good way?

```
Before Sorting
ID ||| Map Score 
----------------
1  ||| 13
2  ||| 15
3  ||| 1
4  ||| 5
5  ||| 6
```

```
After  Sorting
ID ||| Map Score
----------------
2  ||| 15
1  ||| 13
5  ||| 6
4  ||| 5
3  ||| 1
```

I've thought of using a Chord diagram (Python plotly module) but I just want to know if there are any better solutions out there. 
Please advise. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way that came to my mind; using a bar chart for before and after sorting the DataFrame. It might not be the best way though.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Map Score': [13, 15, 1, 5, 6]})

plt.bar(df['ID'], df['Map Score'], align='edge', width=-0.4, label='Before')
df_sort = df.sort_values(by='Map Score', ascending=False)
plt.bar(df['ID'], df_sort['Map Score'], align='edge', width=0.4, label='After')

plt.ylabel('Map Score')
plt.xlabel('ID')
plt.legend()
```

[image]